# dplyr: by-row comparison with matched subset

Tags: r, dplyr

Working with `dplyr`, I am trying to match a row with `n` other rows on a variable, so I can feed the matching set to `summarise()`.  I've only succeeded with a loop so far.  Example data:

```
dfraw <- data.frame( id = c(1:20), age = c(30:35, 32:37, 34:41) )
set.seed(1)
df <- dfraw %>% 
      mutate( var = age + runif(20) - 0.5 ) %>%
      arrange( age )
```

To calculate a z-score of `var` from the five closest matches on age, I can do

```
for ( i in 1:nrow(df) ) {
df$windowedz[i] <- df %>% 
    arrange( abs( df$age[i] - age) ) %>% 
    head(n=6) %>% tail(n=5) %>% # 5 closest matches excluding row `i`
    summarise( (df$var[i] - mean(var) ) / sd(var) ) %>%
    as.numeric
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?  If I use `group_by`, I can't seem to generate a matching group from the individual variable (`df$age[i]` in the example).

Edit: Minor changes for clarification, `arrange` as part of the example data definition, modified loop to insert a scalar rather than a list in column `windowedz`

Edit: With the package `RcppRoll` I was partially successful:

```
library(RcppRoll)
df <- df %>% 
      mutate( 
          mean = roll_mean( var, n = 5, fill = NA ), 
          sd = roll_sd( var, n = 5, fill = NA ), 
          roll_z = (var - mean) / sd 
      )
```

The issue with this solution is that the window contains the value that is to be transformed.  So there is no equivalent to the `head`-`tail` manoeuvre that removes the matched row from the matching set.  Also, this approach gives strange results if I calculate `roll_z` directly instead of calculating `mean` and `sd` first.

Comment: What is your concern here? Performance or just an ugly code?

Comment: Elegance, performance, and also complexity. My "real" data include several more variables that I will probably have to `group_by` or consider in another way. I don't understand how dplyr will interact with the loops and it seems to me that it would be best to avoid them.

Comment: If you are interested in performance then don't use dplyr, especially if we talking by row operations. Not to mention that in your RcppRoll solution dplyr plays no role

Comment: btw, in you RcppRoll solution you haven't sorted by `abs( df$age[i] - age)` which makes it somewhat inconsistent with you original solution.

Comment: I'll backtrack and qualify. I looked at the "data.table vs dplyr" thread and my data is clearly small enough that performance won't be an issue any time soon. Unfortunately it's too late for me to follow your rule of thumb #4: most of the little I know about R is about dplyr. So if I could solve this problem in dplyr, it would ease my learning curve. Having said that, I'll be grateful for each and every piece of advice.

Comment: Re. abs(): I simply haven't found out yet how.